# Compute the Greatest Common Divisor for two polynomials A,B

Tags: polynomials

I'm not sure where to start on this gcd as I don't know a factor to begin the first step of the EEUA

$$A: x^5 - 3x^4 +3x^3 - 2x^2 +2x -4\\
B: x^5 -x^4 -3x^3 -x^2 + x +3$$

Compute the $gcd(A,B)$

Comment: If it helps, $(x-1)$ is a factor of B (I don't know what EEUA is)

Comment: @JohnDoe Presumably some variant of the Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Yeah it's using the extended Euclidean Algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 3 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 4 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  + 3 \right)  $$

$$  \left(   x^{5}  - 3 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 4 \right)  =  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  + 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left( 1  \right) } +  \left(   - 2 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 7 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   - 2 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 7 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 2 }{ 2 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 3 x  - 8 }{ 2 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   - 2 x^{4}  + 6 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  - 7 \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 3 x  - 8 }{ 2 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 20 x  + 48 }{ 25 }  \right) } +  \left(   \frac{ 17 x^{2}  + 17 x  + 17 }{ 25 }  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{3}  - 3 x^{2}  - 3 x  - 8 }{ 2 }  \right)  =  \left(   \frac{ 17 x^{2}  + 17 x  + 17 }{ 25 }  \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 125 x  - 200 }{ 34 }  \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 0}{1} $$ 
 $$ \frac{ 1}{0} $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left( 1  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left( 1  \right) }{ \left( 1  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 2 }{ 2 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{  -  x  }{ 2 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{  -  x  - 2 }{ 2 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{  - 20 x  + 48 }{ 25 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 24 x  + 25 }{ 25 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 4 x  - 23 }{ 25 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$ \color{magenta}{  \left(   \frac{ 125 x  - 200 }{ 34 }  \right) }  \Longrightarrow  \Longrightarrow  \frac{  \left(   \frac{ 25 x^{3}  - 100 x^{2}  + 150 x  - 100 }{ 17 }  \right) }{ \left(   \frac{ 25 x^{3}  - 50 x^{2}  - 50 x  + 75 }{ 17 }  \right) } $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  + 6 x  - 4 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 4 x  - 23 }{ 17 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 24 x  + 25 }{ 17 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 3 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 4 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  - 4 x^{2}  + 6 x  - 4 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  + 3 \right)  =  \left(   x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  - 2 x  + 3 \right)  \cdot \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) } +  \left( 0 \right)  $$ 
 $$  \mbox{GCD} =   \color{magenta}{  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right) }   $$ 
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  - 3 x^{4}  + 3 x^{3}  - 2 x^{2}  + 2 x  - 4 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 4 x  - 23 }{ 17 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{5}  -  x^{4}  - 3 x^{3}  -  x^{2}  +  x  + 3 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 10 x^{2}  - 24 x  + 25 }{ 17 }  \right)  =  \left(   x^{2}  +  x  + 1 \right)  $$