# Euclidean Algorithm for finding GCD of polynomials

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Essentially my question is to find the GCD of the following polynomials using the Euclidean algorithm:

$A:= x^5-3x^4+3x^3-2x^2+2x-4$

$B:= x^5-x^4-3x^3-x^2+x+3$

My attempt:

(Each new remainder will be the following letter of the alphabet. )

$A = 1B +(-2x^4+6x^3-x^2-3x-7) \\ B = (-\frac{x}{2}-1)C+(\frac{5}{2}x^3-\frac{7}{2}x^2-11\frac{x}{2}-4) \\C=(-\frac{4}{5}x+\frac{32}{25})D + (-\frac{23}{25}x^2+\frac{21}{25}x-\frac{47}{25}) \\ D=(-\frac{125}{46}x+\frac{700}{529})E \ + (-\frac{6200}{529}x-\frac{800}{529} \\ E= (\frac{12167}{155000}x - \frac{393047}{4805000})F+(-2.0037)$

At this point I assumed the GCD is $1$ as the remainder is constant.. however I'm 99% sure this is wrong due to the actual factorisation of A and B.

$ A = (x-2)(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+x+1) \\ B = (x-1)(x^2-x-3)(x^2+x+1)$

They clearly have a common factor so I'd expect that $GCD(A,B) = (x^2+x+1) $

I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding something fundamental in terms of the Euclidean Algorithm but not entirely sure what.. any help is appreciated!

Comment: First line $2x-x\ne -3x$

Comment: @JohnWatson Right! I wonder if that error is what's ruined everything on follow through. I shall correct it and try again now. Thanks!

Comment: seems duplicate of this one I answered hours ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499700/compute-the-greatest-common-divisor-for-two-polynomials-a-b/2499796#2499796

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$C = A - B = -2x^4 + 6x^3 - x^2 + x - 7\\
D = B + (\frac 12 x + 1)C = \frac 52 x^3 - \frac 32 x^2 - \frac 32 x - 4$

This appears to be your mistake.

There is no reason why you can't say.

$D = 2B + (x + 2)C =  5 x^3 - 3x^2 - 3x - 8$ to keep it all with integer coefficients.

And sometimes half steps are easier to keep track of.

$E = 5C + 2Dx = 24x^3 - 11x^2 - 11x  - 35\\
F = 24D - 5 E = 17 x^2 +17 x + 17\\
G = x^2 + x  +1$

Comment: I'm not entirely able to follow your process, in terms of finding E,F, G what were you dividing to get the next answer?